# How to add new row in dynamically added columns in a datatable

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatable

I have added some columns to a `datatable` like below.

```vb
OpenConnection()
Dim mmd As New MySqlCommand
Dim mq As String = "SELECT DISTINCT(FeeName) AS FName,UnderSubGroupId FROM master_fee WHERE UnderGroupId=1 ORDER BY UnderSubGroupId ASC"
mmd.Connection = conn
mmd.CommandText = mq
Dim dt As New DataTable

Dim mdr As MySqlDataReader = mmd.ExecuteReader
While mdr.Read
    dt.Columns.Add(Replace(mdr("FName"), " ", "_"))
End While
mdr.Close()
CloseConnection()
```

Now preparing the query to get the data for dynamically added columns.

```vb
Dim dtfrm As String = Convert.ToDateTime(DtpFrom.Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
Dim dtto As String = Convert.ToDateTime(DtpTo.Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

OpenConnection()
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
Dim qry As String = "SELECT " & _
              "DATE_FORMAT(fees_receiving_ledger.DateTaken, '%d/%m/%Y') AS TakenDate," & _
              "fees_receiving_ledger.RcptNo AS Rcpt,"

Dim i As Integer = 1
Dim clm As String
Dim clmAmt As String
For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
  clm = column.ToString
  clmAmt = clm & "_Amount"
  Dim clmCount As Integer = dt.Columns.Count

  If i = clmCount Then
      qry += "Max(Case When fees_receiving_ledger.FeeName = '" & Replace(clm, "_", " ") & "' Then fees_receiving_ledger.FeeAmount Else 0 End) As '" & clmAmt & "'"
  Else
      qry += "Max(Case When fees_receiving_ledger.FeeName = '" & Replace(clm, "_", " ") & "' Then fees_receiving_ledger.FeeAmount Else 0 End) As '" & clmAmt & "',"
      i += 1
  End If
Next
qry += " FROM " & _
       "fees_receiving_ledger " & _
       "WHERE fees_receiving_ledger.DateTaken between '" & dtfrm & "' AND '" & dtto & "' " & _
       "GROUP BY " & _
       "fees_receiving_ledger.RcptNo " & _
       "ORDER BY " & _
       "fees_receiving_ledger.RcptNo"

dt.Columns.Add("TakenDate")
dt.Columns.Add("Rcpt")
```

In `debug` mode, while executing the above `query`, the output is perfect.

So, I have added some columns (dynamically) from a `MySQL` table to a `datatable`.

**Now how do I get the values to add row to the datatable (`dt`) ?**

My table structure is like below...

```vb
CREATE TABLE `fees_receiving_ledger` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RcptNo` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FeeName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FeeAmount` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateTaken` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`receive_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

**NOTE:**

I am replacing the blank space with "_" (underscore) because I am creating an ADO.NET `xml` file to produce a crystal report.

Comment: There is no need to manually add columns to the DT - the data provider does that for you (and you did not do it right).  There is also no need to "format" a date into a string in order to query - *always* use SQL parameters.  I kinda got lost in that soup and cant see where you are trying to add any rows.  Are you trying to manually create the pivot from earlier?

Comment: @Plutonix yes, you are right. I am trying to create the pivot. And I am formatting the date because of mysql.